# OpenJFX packaging with application

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11, openjfx

I am trying to work with JavaFX/OpenJFX. I see that it has dependencies with platform classifier, e.g., `javafx-graphics`, for common platforms (Windows, Linux, etc.). I am looking ahead and I am curious

- if I can just package all the platform .jar files or extracted .class files into resulting distribution ZIP or JAR and it will magically pick up the right one, or
- if I will have to create separate distributions for each of the supported platforms?

Comment: Is this a `Java-11` question? If not, remove the `tag` I added.

Comment: @Sedrick I would say more precisely [tag:javafx-11] and [tag:openjfx]

Comment: I guess @wilx you're using `gradle` for this? Can you update on what do you mean by *I see that it has dependencies with platform classifier*  and which version of dependencies are you using?

Comment: I asked because I think @José Pereda may be following those tags. The question is similar to ones he usually answers.

Comment: There are similar answers for these questions (as @Sedrick suggested), like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791) about a multi-platform fat jar. But the best thing to do is to read the [Getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) about runtime images (fat jar, jlink, cross-platform...). Anyway, while you can do jar distributions, `jlink` and `jpackage` are the way to go nowadays, and these are platform specific.

Comment: @nullpointer No. I am using Maven.